# disable function based on screen size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using jquery to execute hover dropdown menus in bootstrap 4. Works nicely however when I resize to the collapse view (991) I have the dropdowns displayed as block elements to have them opened when the user views rather than have to click or hover the dropdowns. My problem is the function is trying to run and it causes some weird shaky effects when hovering over. Is there a way to disable the function based on the screen size??? Thanks for advice!

```
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
 $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
}, function() {
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(200)
});
```

Comment: If you perform this hover animation in CSS then you don't need to worry about disabling it in JS, as you can just omit the styles under the relevant media size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Modenizr Media Queries for this. If you're not already using Modernizr, you'll need to include it on your project with the `.mq()` feature selected: https://modernizr.com/download?mq-setclasses

Then, within your hover function, you can include a media query. You could include the media query twice, within each callback of your hover event, or you could simplify a bit with the following:

```
$('.navbar .dropdown').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 991px)')) {
        if( e.type == 'mouseenter' ) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
        } else {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(200)
        }
    }
});
```